# Run Remote PS script to deploy software

Tags: powershell, remoting, unc

I am trying to run a powershell script to deploy an MS Access solution to multiple desktops. I have my script on a server share and I have tried to run it with out success. I have used the invoke-command to try and run the script and get this error message

> Access is denied
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + PSComputerName        : TESTVM-PC

I have also run all the psremoting commands and also tried the "Multi-hop" command. All with no success.
I have also tried to  run the actual code in the script and it does not work.

```
Invoke-Command -Computer Dpierson-pc -Credential (get-credential)  -ScriptBlock { 

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -Verbose 

Copy-Item "\\Some\Bogus\Place\Access\*" C:\ -Recurse -Force -Verbose

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Setup.exe"  -PassThru -Verbose
Start-Sleep 30
Stop-Process -name Ninite -Force -Verbose

    }
```

All I get is that the file setup could not be run because it does not exist. and the process then of course cannot be stopped as it does not exist. The credentials are my own and I am a domain admin. Any help would be appreciated. I have thought of making it batch file that I run via a group policy but that is the last thing I want to try as I plan on having more of these in the future. 
P.S. I ran the " Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -Verbose" on the machine locally as well.

Comment: You cannot use PowerShell natively to install user-based GUI apps. A user must be logged on for it to apply to the user. This is a Windows user security boundary, and thus you need a 3rdP solution like Microsoft SysInternals PSExec.exe or use a real software distribution tool like SCCM or GPO to deploy software. Copy the script to the remote host, set a task schedlued to run the install.

Comment: I thought of a GPO but I was hoping to deploy it one at a time, because a limited number of users will be getting it. I may try PSExec.Mostly I am trying to do it without having to log on to the remote computers. So if I set up the scheduled task can the script be on a server referencing the UNC. I have done ST before but always with a local script. Will it copy the files from the server then all i need to do is create a task via the ps script that will run the install locally then delete the task in the script as well.